# Write to file in c ++

Tags: c++

When trying to write various information in a txt file, it is being replaced and only the first data of the last loop is saved.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

ofstream file;

static void drawOptFlowMap(const Mat& flow, Mat& cflowmap, int step, double, const Scalar& color) {
    //cout << "===================== NEW FRAME ======================" << endl;
        for (int y = 0; y < cflowmap.rows; y += step) {
            for (int x = 0; x < cflowmap.cols; x += step)
            {
                const Point2f& fxy = flow.at<Point2f>(y, x);
                line(cflowmap, Point(x, y), Point(cvRound(x + fxy.x), cvRound(y + fxy.y)), color);
                circle(cflowmap, Point(x, y), 2, color, -1);
                file.open("test.txt");
                file << fxy.x << "," << fxy.y << endl;
            }
        }
        file.close();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv, "{help h||}");
    if (parser.has("help")) {
        help();
        return 0;
    }

    VideoCapture cap(0);
    help();

    if (!cap.isOpened())
        return -1;

    Mat flow, cflow, frame, frame1;
    Mat gray, prevgray, uflow;
    namedWindow("flow", 1);
    ofstream myfile;

    for (;;) {
        cap >> frame1;
        Mat frame(frame1(Rect(300, 0, 250, 150)));
        cvtColor(frame, frame, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        if (!prevgray.empty()) {
            calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prevgray, frame, uflow, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0);
            cvtColor(prevgray, cflow, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
            uflow.copyTo(flow);
            drawOptFlowMap(flow, cflow, 20, 1.5, Scalar(0, 255, 0));
            imshow("flow", cflow);
            VideoWriter(gray);
        }

        if (waitKey(30) >= 0)
            break;
            swap(prevgray, frame);
            myfile.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The data I want to save is in the drawOptFlowMap function, but only the first information in the last frame is saved. Any suggestions on how I can solve it?

Comment: Move the `file.open()` to before the loop. Note: the code indentation is off, e.g. for the `swap` statement. Consider using a free formatting tool such as AStyle before posting code.

Answer (score 1):

You open and close file within the loop body. While sometimes it's a legit approach, e.g. to maintain file integrity in case the next iteration would fail catastrophically, this is source of bug in your case.

`open` is defined as:

```
void open( const char *filename,
           ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in|ios_base::out );
// more variants for different  string  types follow.
```

`file.open("test.txt");` would open file for reading and writing, any of previous content would be lost because seek would be at starting position and default value of `mode` is `ios_base::in|ios_base::out`. If file didn't exist, it would be created. Next write operation would overwrite previously written data.

Here is documentation on that method: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open

You need add `ios_base::app` or `ios_base::ate` to begin appending to the end of file, or change algorithm of your program. The former would seek to the end of file after each write (a redundant operation if you do not change file position pointer). The latter would seek to the end of file after `open`.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not a minimal example. Anyway, the problem is that your `file.open("test.txt");` is within the for loop